# TeamCity Build with mixed (.Net Framework + .Net Core) projects solution - Is it possible?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, .net-core

**Context**: Consider a Visual Studio 2017 solution with number of projects targeting .NET 4.6.1; In TeamCity a MSBuild Runner is used for the build - A new .Net Core library project was introduced to this solution that obviously broke the build... The artefacts of this build are number of NuGet packages after successful NUnit test step.

**My question is**: Is it even possible and what is the best approach to have a mixed .NET Framework & .NET Core projects in the same solution?

**Options**:

- I guess the obvious approach will be to separate the .NET Core code in pure VS .Net Core solution and use the TeamCity .NET Core build runner...
- I am also exploring the option of creating a custom build script to execute from TeamCity that can handle the nature of both .NET package restore and build worlds... or may be this is not a good idea?

Comment: Is VS 2017 with .net core support installed on the agent? if so, msbuild 15 should be able to build the full solution without problems.

Comment: VS2017 Build tools are installed on the agent indeed, however the problem I see in TeamCity (unless I am missing something) is that there are separate Runners for the .Net Framework and dotnet core; also the packages are restored differently for each runner... I guess the only way to have a mixed solution with dotnet core and to get TeamCity to build it is via custom build script using something like [psake](https://github.com/psake/psake) or [fake](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE)

Comment: Ah yes the build tools can't build core apps at the moment, full VS msbuild can: see https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1697.
The `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` command works work on "full" projects as well as long as they are plain logic apps.

Comment: @Emil "A new .Net Core library" - the library will be presumably netstandard not netcore - and you can [multi-target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) e.g. netstandard2.0 and net461 to get around any referencing issues. `dotnet build` is able to target whatever target you like.